# How to pass the image from Activity B to previous Activity A on Back pressed by shared preference android

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, startactivityforresult

I want to change the image of previous activity if I changed the image of second activity and when I return back to previous activity the image should be changed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bTnj.png

Comment: is your picture saved in sd card or something?

Comment: i have taken the image from gallery and saved in the same activity but want to pass that image in the previous activity

Comment: I wouldn't use SharedPreference, unless its a permanent setting you want to last between runs.  Regardless, the answer is to use startActivityForResult and change the image in onActivityResult

Comment: can you give the code how to pass the image by forResult from B to A activity how to retrieve the image in A activity

Comment: As mentioned use startActivityForResult and set the file path of the image as result of your second activity. It's the same way how you handle to pick a image from the Gallery. Maybe you want to have a look on this http://androidbitmaps.blogspot.de/2015/04/loading-images-in-android-part-iii-pick.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to customize following code within your code. And it will work.

Here is the first activity where you want to track if the image is changed and want to load changed image.

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        //YOUR OTHER CODE HERE..

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(A.this, B.class), 111);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getExtras() != null) {
                //set your image path which has been returned by previous activity to your imageview here
                //data.getExtras().getString("image_path")
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Here is your next activity where you are changing image

```
public class B extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        //YOUR OTHER CODE HERE..
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("image_path", "CHANGED_IMAGE_PATH");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set the imageview with image path?

Comment: You can use any third party library to do that. For more reference check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213832/load-image-in-android-studio